# Eclipse not showing code in the Java Editor perspective

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working in Eclipse with some packages and then suddenly the java editor perspective doesn't show any code and it's blue, just like in the photo bellow:
[image]

I tried everything, from resetting the perspective to cleaning the project, even installed a new version of Eclipse. If i select the entire content of the .java file then pass it to a txt file the code is still there.

[image]

Comment: The "setup check 24%" bother me, no idea of what it could be. But you probably have a corrupted file in eclipse.

Comment: Well, i deleted the old version and installed a new one and it did not fix the problem

Comment: @AndreiSebastian, is the issue related to the single workspace?

Comment: Recreate your project from a fresh checkout in a new workspace.  Do not  carry metadata files over.

Comment: @SergeyProkofiev I am using a single workspace at the moment, I will try a new workspace

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i did as you said but it did nothing, it's the same

Comment: Interesting.  If you are certain you did not carry any metadata files over from the old workspace, you may have run into an operating system setting you have changed.   Just to be certain, you have not messed with colors in either the surrounding operating system or in Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen no, i did not change anything, i tried to reset to default but same outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like after 2 days Eclipse just started working normal.

Answer (score 0):

Just open Windows(Option at the top) --> Show View --> Console.